# R: Recursive Averages

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language. I have the following data:

```
library(dplyr)

my_data = data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,5), var_1 = sample(c(0,1), 15, replace = TRUE) , var_2 =sample(c(0,1), 15 , replace = TRUE) )

my_data = data.frame(my_data %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(index = row_number(id)))

my_data = my_data[,c(1,4,2,3)]
```

The data looks something like this:

```
   id index var_1 var_2
1   1     1     0     1
2   1     2     0     0
3   1     3     1     1
4   1     4     0     1
5   2     1     1     0
6   2     2     1     1
7   2     3     0     1
8   3     1     1     0
9   4     1     0     0
10  4     2     0     0
11  5     1     0     0
12  5     2     1     0
13  5     3     0     1
14  5     4     0     0
15  5     5     0     1
```

I want to create two new variables (v_1, v_2). For each unique "id":

- v_1: I want v_1 to be the average value of the current, previous and previous-to-previous values of var_1 (i.e. index = n, index = n-1 and index = n-2). When this is not possible (e.g. for index = 2 and index = 1), I want this average to be for as back as you can go.
- v_2: I want v_2 to be the average value of the current, previous and previous-to-previous values of var_2 (i.e. index = n, index = n-1 and index = n-2). When this is not possible (e.g. for index = 2 and index = 1), I want this average to be for as back as you can go.

This would be something like this:

- row 1 (id = 1, index = 1) : v_1 = var_1 (index 1)
- row 2 (id = 1, index = 1 ; id = 1 index = 2) : v_1 = (var_1 (index 1) + var_1 (index 2))/2
- row 3 (id = 1, index = 1 ; id = 1 index = 2; id = 1, index = 3) : v_1 = (var_1 (index 1) + var_1 (index 2) + var_1 (index 3)) /3
- row 4 (id = 1, index = 2 ; id = 1 index = 3; id = 1, index = 4) : v_1 = (var_1 (index 2) + var_1 (index 3) + var_1 (index 4)) /3
- etc.

I tried to do this with the following code:

```
average_data = my_data %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   summarise(v_1 = mean(tail(var_1, 3)), 
             v_2 = mean(tail(var_2, 3)))

# final_result
final_data =  merge(x = my_data, y = average_data, by = "id", all.x = TRUE)
```

But I am not sure if this is correct.

**Can someone please show me how to do this?**

Thanks!

Comment: Is none of the solutions given solves this?

Answer (score 5):

**data**

```r
df <- data.frame(
    id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L),
    index = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L),
    var_1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
    var_2 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L)
  )
```

**tidyverse**

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("var_"),
                .fns = ~zoo::rollapply(data = .x, width = 3, FUN = mean, partial = TRUE, align = "right"),
                .names = "new_{.col}")) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 15 × 6
#>       id index var_1 var_2 new_var_1 new_var_2
#>    <int> <int> <int> <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1     1     1     0     1     0         1    
#>  2     1     2     0     0     0         0.5  
#>  3     1     3     1     1     0.333     0.667
#>  4     1     4     0     1     0.333     0.667
#>  5     2     1     1     0     1         0    
#>  6     2     2     1     1     1         0.5  
#>  7     2     3     0     1     0.667     0.667
#>  8     3     1     1     0     1         0    
#>  9     4     1     0     0     0         0    
#> 10     4     2     0     0     0         0    
#> 11     5     1     0     0     0         0    
#> 12     5     2     1     0     0.5       0    
#> 13     5     3     0     1     0.333     0.333
#> 14     5     4     0     0     0.333     0.333
#> 15     5     5     0     1     0         0.667
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**data.table**

```r
library(data.table)

COLS <- gsub("ar", "", grep("var_", names(df), value = TRUE))

setDT(df)[, 
          (COLS) := lapply(.SD, function(x) zoo::rollapply(data = x, width = 3, FUN = mean, partial = TRUE, align = "right")),
          by = id,
          .SDcols = patterns("var_")][]
#>     id index var_1 var_2       v_1       v_2
#>  1:  1     1     0     1 0.0000000 1.0000000
#>  2:  1     2     0     0 0.0000000 0.5000000
#>  3:  1     3     1     1 0.3333333 0.6666667
#>  4:  1     4     0     1 0.3333333 0.6666667
#>  5:  2     1     1     0 1.0000000 0.0000000
#>  6:  2     2     1     1 1.0000000 0.5000000
#>  7:  2     3     0     1 0.6666667 0.6666667
#>  8:  3     1     1     0 1.0000000 0.0000000
#>  9:  4     1     0     0 0.0000000 0.0000000
#> 10:  4     2     0     0 0.0000000 0.0000000
#> 11:  5     1     0     0 0.0000000 0.0000000
#> 12:  5     2     1     0 0.5000000 0.0000000
#> 13:  5     3     0     1 0.3333333 0.3333333
#> 14:  5     4     0     0 0.3333333 0.3333333
#> 15:  5     5     0     1 0.0000000 0.6666667
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

I would say this is moving average, and it can be impemented by a function `f` like below, using `embed` (preferrable) or `sapply` (less efficient, not recommanded), and run it group-wisely using `ave`:

```
f <- function(v, n = 3) {
    rowMeans(embed(c(rep(NA, n-1), v), n), na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

or

```
f <- function(v, n = 3) {
    sapply(
        seq_along(v),
        function(k) sum(v[pmax(k - n + 1, 1):k]) / pmin(k, n)
    )
}
```

and then we run

```
transform(
    df,
    v1 = ave(var_1, id, FUN = f),
    v2 = ave(var_2, id, FUN = f)
)
```

such that

```
   id index var_1 var_2        v1        v2
1   1     1     0     1 0.0000000 1.0000000
2   1     2     0     0 0.0000000 0.5000000
3   1     3     1     1 0.3333333 0.6666667
4   1     4     0     1 0.3333333 0.6666667
5   2     1     1     0 1.0000000 0.0000000
6   2     2     1     1 1.0000000 0.5000000
7   2     3     0     1 0.6666667 0.6666667
8   3     1     1     0 1.0000000 0.0000000
9   4     1     0     0 0.0000000 0.0000000
10  4     2     0     0 0.0000000 0.0000000
11  5     1     0     0 0.0000000 0.0000000
12  5     2     1     0 0.5000000 0.0000000
13  5     3     0     1 0.3333333 0.3333333
14  5     4     0     0 0.3333333 0.3333333
15  5     5     0     1 0.0000000 0.6666667
```

Comment: what I like with your answers is that I often discover a new R function ;-) Upvoted

Comment: @Waldi Thanks! I guess `embed` is the thing you are interested :) I learnt it from akrun long time ago

Answer (score 2):

You could create a function that acomplishes this:

```
library(tidyverse)

fun <- function(x, k){
   y <- cummean(first(x, k-1))
   if(k > length(x)) y else c(y, zoo::rollmean(x, k))
 }

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(v_1 = fun(var_1, 3), v_2 = fun(var_2, 3))

# Groups:   id [5]
      id index var_1 var_2   v_1   v_2
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1     0     1 0     1    
 2     1     2     0     0 0     0.5  
 3     1     3     1     1 0.333 0.667
 4     1     4     0     1 0.333 0.667
 5     2     1     1     0 1     0    
 6     2     2     1     1 1     0.5  
 7     2     3     0     1 0.667 0.667
 8     3     1     1     0 1     0    
 9     4     1     0     0 0     0    
10     4     2     0     0 0     0    
11     5     1     0     0 0     0    
12     5     2     1     0 0.5   0    
13     5     3     0     1 0.333 0.333
14     5     4     0     0 0.333 0.333
15     5     5     0     1 0     0.667
```

Comment: @ onyambu : thank you so much for your answer! I wonder if there is a 'ready-made" function in R that already allows you to do this?

Comment: @stats_noob I do not think there is. Although it should be there since matlab has the `smooth` function that does the same thing though with a default of 5 observatiosn

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried your code and got the following error: Error in UseMethod("group_by") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: Do you know what I am doing wrong? Thank you so much!

Comment: @stats_noob you should have `my_data %>%group_by....` not `df %>%group_by` i called my data `df`

Comment: I tried this correction: final = my_data %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(v_1 = fun(var_1, 3), v_2 = fun(var_2, 3))

Comment: Now I get a new error: Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `v_1 = fun(var_1, 3)`.
x `v_1` must be size 4 or 1, not 3.
i The error occurred in group 1: id = 1.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred. ... I wonder what could be wrong....I will keep working on this!

Comment: @stats_noob are you running the code exactly as given above? No error on my side. ie change the `df` to `my_data` which you have above(in the question)

Comment: @ onyambu : thank you for your reply! i think I copied everything correctly, I will try to see if there is a mistake on my part...

Comment: Here is a screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/L3sjYSO

Comment: @stats_noob it states that the error occurred in group 1. Consider doing `fun(df$var_1[df$id == 1], 3)` and see what it produces. Check as to whether it produces correct values that you would expect. And whether the length is the same as the length of the input

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using only built in functions and `dplyr`:

```r
my_data %>% 
  mutate(
    row = seq_along(id),
    v_1 = (var_1 + lag(var_1, default = 0) + lag(var_1, 2, default = 0))/pmin(row, 3),
    v_2 = (var_2 + lag(var_2, default = 0) + lag(var_2, 2, default = 0))/pmin(row, 3)
  )
#>    id index var_1 var_2 row       v_1       v_2
#> 1   1     1     0     1   1 0.0000000 1.0000000
#> 2   1     2     1     0   2 0.5000000 0.5000000
#> 3   1     3     1     1   3 0.6666667 0.6666667
#> 4   1     4     1     0   4 1.0000000 0.3333333
#> 5   2     1     0     1   5 0.6666667 0.6666667
#> 6   2     2     0     1   6 0.3333333 0.6666667
#> 7   2     3     1     1   7 0.3333333 1.0000000
#> 8   3     1     1     1   8 0.6666667 1.0000000
#> 9   4     1     1     1   9 1.0000000 1.0000000
#> 10  4     2     1     1  10 1.0000000 1.0000000
#> 11  5     1     0     1  11 0.6666667 1.0000000
#> 12  5     2     0     1  12 0.3333333 1.0000000
#> 13  5     3     0     0  13 0.0000000 0.6666667
#> 14  5     4     0     0  14 0.0000000 0.3333333
#> 15  5     5     1     0  15 0.3333333 0.0000000
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

`dplyr::lag()` gives you the previuous values of your variable. If they don't exist, we swap them for `0`, basically ignoring them. To get the average we divide on `pmax(seq_along(<any variable>, 3))`, which will be `1` for the first row, `2` for the second, and `3` for all other rows.

This will also work on a grouped dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` (which is hidden when loading `dplyr`) or `convolve` and `ave` for grouping.

```
fun <- function(x) {
  . <- if(length(x) > 2) stats::filter(x, c(1,1,1)/3, side=1)[-2:-1] else NULL
  #. <- if(length(x) > 2) convolve(x, c(1,1,1)/3, , type = "filter") else NULL #Alternative
  c(cummean(x[1:min(2, length(x))]), .)
}

my_data$v_1 <- ave(my_data$var_1, my_data$id, FUN=fun)
my_data$v_2 <- ave(my_data$var_2, my_data$id, FUN=fun)
my_data
#   id index var_1 var_2       v_1       v_2
#1   1     1     1     1 1.0000000 1.0000000
#2   1     2     1     1 1.0000000 1.0000000
#3   1     3     0     1 0.6666667 1.0000000
#4   1     4     1     1 0.6666667 1.0000000
#5   2     1     0     1 0.0000000 1.0000000
#6   2     2     0     0 0.0000000 0.5000000
#7   2     3     1     0 0.3333333 0.3333333
#8   3     1     0     0 0.0000000 0.0000000
#9   4     1     0     1 0.0000000 1.0000000
#10  4     2     0     0 0.0000000 0.5000000
#11  5     1     1     0 1.0000000 0.0000000
#12  5     2     0     1 0.5000000 0.5000000
#13  5     3     0     0 0.3333333 0.3333333
#14  5     4     1     0 0.3333333 0.3333333
#15  5     5     0     1 0.3333333 0.3333333
```

Or using `cumsum`:

```
fun2 <- function(x, n=3) {
  (cumsum(x) - head(cumsum(c(rep(0, n), x)), -n)) / pmin(n, seq_along(x)) }

my_data$v_1 <- ave(my_data$var_1, my_data$id, FUN=fun2)
my_data$v_2 <- ave(my_data$var_2, my_data$id, FUN=fun2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a try with a simple function `avg` to return this type of average

```r
library(dplyr , warn.conflicts = FALSE)

set.seed(1978)

my_data = data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,5), var_1 = sample(c(0,1), 15, replace = TRUE) , var_2 =sample(c(0,1), 15 , replace = TRUE) )

my_data = data.frame(my_data %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(index = row_number(id)))

my_data = my_data[,c(1,4,2,3)]


#===================================
avg <- function(x){
  t <- rep(c(T,NA) , c(3 , length(x) - 1))
  m <- numeric(length(x))
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    m [i]<- mean(x[t[3:length(t)]] , na.rm = TRUE)
    t <- lag(t)
  }
  m
}
#===================================

library(tidyverse)

my_data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(v_1 = avg(var_1), v_2 = avg(var_2))
#> # A tibble: 15 × 6
#> # Groups:   id [5]
#>       id index var_1 var_2   v_1   v_2
#>    <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     1     1     0     0 0     0    
#>  2     1     2     1     0 0.5   0    
#>  3     1     3     1     0 0.667 0    
#>  4     1     4     1     1 1     0.333
#>  5     2     1     0     1 0     1    
#>  6     2     2     1     1 0.5   1    
#>  7     2     3     0     0 0.333 0.667
#>  8     3     1     1     0 1     0    
#>  9     4     1     1     1 1     1    
#> 10     4     2     0     1 0.5   1    
#> 11     5     1     1     1 1     1    
#> 12     5     2     1     0 1     0.5  
#> 13     5     3     0     1 0.667 0.667
#> 14     5     4     1     0 0.667 0.333
#> 15     5     5     1     0 0.667 0.333
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This uses dplyr's `across` with [slider's](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/02/slider-0-1-0/) `slide_dbl`; both from the tidyverse. Slider handles partial windows, so is well-suited to this problem.

(`%>%` may be used instead of the native pipe `|>`.)

```r
library(dplyr)
library(slider)

# Sample Data
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L),
  index = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L),
  var_1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
  var_2 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L)
)

# Possible answer
df |> 
  group_by(id) |> 
  mutate(across(starts_with("var_"), ~ slide_dbl(., mean, .before = 2), .names = "{.col}_mean")) |> 
  ungroup()

#> # A tibble: 15 × 6
#>       id index var_1 var_2 var_1_mean var_2_mean
#>    <int> <int> <int> <int>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1     1     1     0     1      0          1    
#>  2     1     2     0     0      0          0.5  
#>  3     1     3     1     1      0.333      0.667
#>  4     1     4     0     1      0.333      0.667
#>  5     2     1     1     0      1          0    
#>  6     2     2     1     1      1          0.5  
#>  7     2     3     0     1      0.667      0.667
#>  8     3     1     1     0      1          0    
#>  9     4     1     0     0      0          0    
#> 10     4     2     0     0      0          0    
#> 11     5     1     0     0      0          0    
#> 12     5     2     1     0      0.5        0    
#> 13     5     3     0     1      0.333      0.333
#> 14     5     4     0     0      0.333      0.333
#> 15     5     5     0     1      0          0.667
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>